# does mySql workbench have command line silent install

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am attempting to install MySQL workbench silently during the install of my application, then will want to set up a server environment and schema.

I can manage this in standard MySQL server, but cannot figure out how to do it in workbench, or if this is even a possibility.